# Conjunction with verb "to work for"

Tags: prepositions

Is it:

> I'd like to work for Coca Cola or for Pepsi.

or can I also say

> I'd like to work for Coca Cola or Pepsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't about a conjunction. Both sentences have the conjunction "or", which is a coordinating conjunction (it connects two grammatically equal things).

In the first example, it is
work ((for A) or (for B)).
(The coordination is of two preposition phrases).

In the second example the coordination is
work for (A or B).
(The coordination is of two nouns).

Both forms are grammatical and mean the same thing.